# DC.js, crossfilter - running reduce() on groupAll()

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

This feels like it should be easy :/

The crossfilter API says I can run a reduce on groupAll:
https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#groupAll_reduce

But I cannot get it to work. I've tried facts.groupAll() where var facts = crossfilter(data); And I've tried all.reduce() where var all = facts.groupAll(). I've tried with and without brackets and googled for examples. Does anyone know of a working example? I want a single output across all my rows.

I realise my reduce function isn't complete and looks complicated. It works fine reducing a dimension, but gives undefined for groupAll on facts.

Thanks

```
  var accumGrp = facts.groupAll().reduce(
    function(p,v) {
      for (var i=0; i<supplierFields[0].length; i++) {
        if (!p.population[supplierFields[0][i]]) { p.population[supplierFields[0][i]] = []; }
        p.population[supplierFields[0][i]].push(v[supplierFields[0][i]+'_l']);
      }
      return p;
    },
    function(p,v) { return p; },
    function() {
      var obj = {};
      obj.population = {};
      obj.highlight = {};
      return obj;
    }
  );

  print_filter('accumGrp');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem here is probably that you need to call `groupAll.value()` in order to execute the group aggregation, whereas regular groups calculate aggregations at the time of definition or data load, not when you query them with `group.top` or `group.all`.

It looks like your basic approach is otherwise correct, and I can't see what `print_filter` does, so it's just a guess, but try calling `console.log(accumGrp.value())` at the end of your script and see if it works.

If not, here is a short working example to reference:

```
var data = [1,2,3,4]

var cf = crossfilter(data)
var grp = cf.groupAll().reduce(
  function(p, d) { return p + d },
  function(p, d) { return p - d },
  function() { return 0 }
)

console.log(grp.value())
```

This prints `10`. And here is a working JSFiddle where you can try things out (with a few more console statements that might help look into what is going on): https://jsfiddle.net/esjewett/39xgn5ah/1/